# find and count iframe in web page and copy number of frame to script imacros

Tags: javascript, iframe, imacros

this my code to count frame on web page

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.location.href='javascript:{var<SP>f=[];
var<SP>l=window.frames.length;for(i=0;i<l;i++){
try{
f.push("\\""+window.frames[i].name+"\\"");
}catch(e){
f.push("no_frame_name")}}alert("FOUND<SP>"+f.length+"<SP>FRAMES:"+"\\n\\n"+f.join("\\n"));}';
undefined;
}
```

and then my question how to copy or move number of frame from above command imacros? please help me answer of this questions will be very usefully for me, tanks for anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro:

```
SET S "var doc = window.document; var elt = doc.createElement('input'); elt.type = 'hidden'; elt.id = 'myFrameNumber'; elt.value = window.frames.length; doc.body.appendChild(elt); undefined;"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=ID:myFrameNumber EXTRACT=TXT
URL GOTO=javascript:{doc.body.removeChild(doc.getElementById("myFrameNumber"));undefined;}
SET frameNumber {{!EXTRACT}}
'PROMPT {{frameNumber}}
```

Comment: wow!! it's work your code, i'am very interesting tank very very much,, and then how your write to this code, can you explain every command to get count number of fram web page?

Comment: If all of the 'iMacros' commands are understandable for you, just learn the basis of JavaScript. And that will be the best explanation.